# For a point charge, how does $a_\mu a^{\mu} = 0$ imply that $\dot a^\mu = 0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, classical-electrodynamics

I'm reading the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0405121), Radiation reaction reexamined: bound momentum and Schott term by Dmitri Gal'tsov. With $a^\mu$ the four-acceleration of a point charge, he writes at the bottom of page 1:

> Indeed, if one has $a_\mu a^{\mu} = 0$ at any time, then it is easy to
>   show that the three-acceleration is zero, $a = 0$, and therefore
>   $\dot a^\mu = 0$.

The first part is obviously true because $a_\mu a^{\mu}$ is a Lorentz invariant, and evaluated in the proper frame gives $a^2= 0$. But I don't see how this then implies $\dot a^\mu = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that "any time" means "every time" actually. It holds $v^cv_c=-1$, where $v$ is the four-velocity, so taking the derivative with respect to the proper time we also have $a_cv^c=0$. This identity implies that $a_0=0$ in the rest frame of the particle. If, in addition, the constraint is valid $a_ca^c=0$ at every instant of  proper time, this identity, again considered in the rest frame of the particle, implies $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a} =0$ at every time. Thus all components of $a$ vanish in that reference frame. As we are dealing with a four-vector, its components vanish in every reference frame at every instant of proper time.

Comment: Yes, this is true if $a_ca^c=0$ for every time, whereas the text says for any time. I'm beginning to think that because the author is Russian, he isn't aware of the subtle difference in interpretation for an English speaker between "every time" and "any time". I'd like to vote your answer as correct, so could you edit your answer to include this point?

Comment: Done! Indeed I automatically intepreted any time as every time. I have to admit that  sometimes I also have difficulties in interpreting the meaning of "any" in English.